# Call a function only when fired by an event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
format : function(){
   //function body
   if(condition){
       //execute this condition only on focus event 
   }
}
```

This function is being called on page load and on the focus of an input element. I have a condition within this function that I would like to be called only when this function is called manually from the focus event and not on page load. Is there a way to achieve this?

There are cases sometimes when the 'condition' in the if statement is true on page load as well. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any focus event, or a specific element's focus event?

Comment: I have four input elements on the page, the function is set up such that I have access to the element there, basically i am passing the  elements reference there.

Comment: I suggest making an abstracted function, and simply attach it to the focus event (DOM event) as needed

Answer (score 3):

Separate into two functions:

```
format: function() {
    //Do stuff for focus
}
onload: function() {
    //Do stuff for onload
    this.format();
}
```

Comment: Not really, the colons in OP's example code imply that it's an object. `this` will work just fine if you call the function correctly. Also, it's just an example, this will work very well without the object.

Comment: _if you call the function correctly_, that being a problem I've seen asked here dozens of times.  If it's simply passed as a reference it _won't_ work.

Answer (score 2):

You can just check for the presence of an `event` parameter:

```
format: function(event) {
    if (event) {
        // called form an event
    } else {
        // called manually (without a parameter)
    }
}
```

For further robustness, check the `event.type` parameter - it'll contain the name of the event that fired.

Answer (score 2):

Just use event parameter.

```
format : function(e){
   //function body
   if(e && e.type == 'focus'){
       //execute this condition only on focus event 
   }
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mbL5ohwr/**

Answer (score 0):

you can just was an argument when calling manually on focus and check for no of argument like with special keyword "arguments", when you call it on page load without an argument then length will be zero else it wont be zero , so condition will be true for focus functionality only

```
format : function(){

 if(arguments.length){
   //execute this condition only on focus event 
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the element has focus, using for example `this === document.activeElement` or `$(this).is(':focus')`. If the function is fired through the focus event, these will return `true` and if they're called from the onload event, these will return `false`.

I hope this helped you!

Answer (score 0):

just thought to share:
This is what worked for me from the solutions provided to me, thanks for it:

```
format : function(e){
 //function body
 if(e && e.type == 'focus'){
   //execute this condition only on focus event 
 }
}
```

Just an FYI, we do not explicitly need to pass the event param, it can be as simple as this:

```
format : function(){
 //function body
 if(e && e.type == 'focus'){
    //execute this condition only on focus event 
 }
}
```

e will by default have the reference of the event by which it was caused. Thanks for all of the input.

Comment: Not sure what is the purpose of reposting already another posted answer. BTW, `e` is undefined in second example, aren't you confusing it with `event`? Anyway, `event||e` should always be defined for cross browsers support

Comment: and if the event handler is registered using jQuery, then the `event` parameter is guaranteed to be passed.

Comment: So this is the issue I am facing. The function has 2 arguements - element,p where p is an optional parameter. If I use it the second way, it works fine in chrome and IE, but in firefox it gives me an error saying event is undefined, any suggestions? Or how can i pass the event reference to the function itself?

Comment: @jp310 perhaps you should have included that detail in the question?   As written, those parameters _shouldn't_ work in an event handling situation.

Comment: @Alnitak: My bad, guess your correct, but I just faced this issue after I implemented the solution, any suggestions?

Comment: @jp310 yeah - _edit your question to include detail of the actual function and how it's being called!_